# I Have a windows form application in C# and want to publish it in a LAN via ASP.NET ??

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, winforms

I have made a C# Windows Forms application and connected it with Microsoft SQL Server.

I want to allow all machines in the LAN to use the program and connect to the SQL server but without having to set up the program on all the machines.

I wondered if I can do this with ASP.NET.
How do I do it? Are there any tutorials for this sort of task?
Anything on the difference between web forms, MVC  Web API .. ETC.

Comment: Why not just put it on a network share and have people run it from there?

Comment: because there will be some updates in the app so i will not have to change the update in the other machines.

Comment: Unclear what you are looking for: "publish" feel like some sort of setup (like OneClick), but the post feels more about "convert WinForms to ASP.Net MVC/WebForms site".

Comment: your question title and description seems to be contradictory. Do you want to create an ASP.Net Application to share EXE file? Or do you want to create Web application with Winforms functionality? Either the case you have to get started from http://www.asp.net/ because your question is too broad to answer.

Comment: and also i don't know if all the machines can run the app simultaneously if the app is just get shared through the LAN

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov : "convert WinForms to ASP.Net MVC/WebForms site" that's what i meant exactly

Comment: I think that (WinForm => ASP.Net conversion) would be too broad for SO. Check out previous question for similar topic - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+convert+winform+asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy! Create an empty Web Forms project, drag controls onto it in the same manner you did with your desktop application. Then add your code, objects, logic, etc => see what you've got in the browser and if you like that publish it to the server and guess what?...RIGHT! Now it's accessible over the network without any need to install the desktop version.
Hope that answers your question.

Comment: that's really help , but the problem i will need lot of time to rebuilt the application but in the empty web form , so is there any solution to convert my winFORM app to web app ?

Comment: another note i opened an empty web app and there is no available toolbox components !!

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way of automated conversion of Win Forms app into the web based one. Try hitting CTRL+ALT+X in Visual Studio to open ToolBox. If it's empty - create an aspx page and open it, tools should appear after doing that.

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to install your winforms applications on all of the systems assigning servers ip in your software in each individual system.
What you can do is to copy your classes to web application and I think you can copy controls of winforms to web forms. Please give it a try. yes, will have to change different things if it doesn't allow copying controls. cheers.